# Cut out all of a square array except for a specified NxN section in the middle in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

How can I take the following square array (or any other square array ebtered by the user) and take the center NxN square?
For example:

```
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    10   11   12
13   14   15   16
```

is entered along with specifications for the middle 2x2, so it becomes

```
6    7
10   11
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
function [FinalMatrix] = arraycenter(x, m)
% arraycenter takes a large square NxN matrix and trims away everything
% other than the center 'm'x'm' submatrix.
% x must be a square 2 dimension matrix that is at least 3x3
% m must be an integer less than or equal to N, and if N is even, m
% must be even, and vice versa

% Find dimensions of x and check to make sure it is a square, 2D matrix
columndim = size(x, 1);
rowdim = size(x, 2);
pagedim = size(x, 3);
if columndim < 2 || rowdim < 2 || pagedim ~= 1
    error('Your first matrix entered was not two dimensional. Try again.')
end
if columndim ~= rowdim
    error('Your first matrix was not a square. Try again.')
end

% Make sure m is the correct size
if m >= columndim || m >= rowdim
    error('m is too large. Try again.')
end

% Make sure N and m match (N is odd, m is odd; N is even, m is even)
if rem(rowdim, 2) == 0 && rem(m, 2) == 1
    error('N is even and m is odd. Try again.')
end
if rem(rowdim, 2) == 1 && rem(m, 2) == 0
    error('N is odd and m is even. Try again.')
end

% Perform the operation to find the center matrix
end
```

As you can see, I have done all the data validation. I am stuck on the actual performance of the task.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what if the array size N is odd? say 5x5 ?

Comment: Do you know about array indexing? Eg: if `A = [4 5 6 7]` then what is `A(1)`, `A(3:4)`. Then trying indexing 2D arrays and you should be a lot closer to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following function crops out a square matrix from center of another. It does not control the even/odd criteria implemented in your code. If equal margins cannot be created according to the dimensions of `x` and the value of `m`, the top and left margins will be smaller than the right and bottom margins by one element.

```
function [y, sI, eI] = arraycenter(x, m)
% returns an m by m matrix from center of square matrix x
% startIndex and endIndex are index of first and last 
%   column (or row) if x that will be copied to y,
%   so that y = x(sI:eI, sI:eI)

% check if x is a square 2d matrix
sz = size(x);
if ~ismatrix(x) || sz(1)~=sz(2)
    error('x must be a square 2D matrix');
end

% check id m is equal or less than d
d = sz(1);
if m>d
    error('m must be equal or less than size(x, 1).');
end

sI = floor((d-m)/2)+1;
eI = sI+m-1;
y = x(sI:eI, sI:eI);

end
```

But if you insist to inform caller that all margins will not be equal, you can add the following control as well:

```
if mod((d-m), 2)
    warning('y can not be exactly at the center of x.');
end
```

Use it like:

```
n = 5;
M = magic(n)
for i=1:n
    fprintf('%dx%d:\n', i, i);
    disp(arraycenter(M, i));
end
```

> M =
>
> ```
>   17    24     1     8    15  
>   23     5     7    14    16  
>    4     6    13    20    22  
>   10    12    19    21     3  
>   11    18    25     2     9
> ```
>
> 1x1:
>
> ```
>   13
> ```
>
> 2x2:
>
> ```
>    5     7  
>    6    13
> ```
>
> 3x3:
>
> ```
>    5     7    14  
>    6    13    20  
>   12    19    21
> ```
>
> 4x4:
>
> ```
>   17    24     1     8  
>   23     5     7    14  
>    4     6    13    20  
>   10    12    19    21
> ```
>
> 5x5:
>
> ```
>   17    24     1     8    15  
>   23     5     7    14    16  
>    4     6    13    20    22  
>   10    12    19    21     3  
>   11    18    25     2     9
> ```